# Export to MS Excel 97-2003 is not there in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report Viewer OCX on a VB 6.0 form to show the reports. I need to export the reports in XLSX format due to 65k limit in XLS format but the required format is not there on the control's export option

[image]

I have Excel 2007 installed on my machine and I have tried CR 8.5, CR 2011 and CR 2016 but the option is not there. The setup was executed from my machine with "Run as administrator"

ProductID of CR 2011 is `BuildVersion=14.0.2.364.CR_${MY_BUILD_NAME}`

ProductID of CR 2016 is `BuildVersion=14.2.6.2839.crystalreports_aurora42_sp_rel`. Key was provided by SAP via email, i used the same Key to install CR 2011.

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the old COM object model. That version doesn't support export to xlsx. Need to move to the .NET object model to get that option (assuming you are using the Excel Data Only option).